# Keras compatibility issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook

I got some code from last year but now I'm trying to run it on my laptop and I get some errors. I think it's because of the conversion of Keras 2 to Keras 3, but I'm not sure.

So my first problem I encountered was keras.models.load_model doesn't work with the model. So I got an error saying that I had to use keras.layers.TFSMLayer. I did that and it worked but then later on I wanted to use model.predict but then it says that TFSMLayer doesn't has this. So now I'm stuck

This is the original code snippet where it wouldn't load my model:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('UNetW_bs32_ep25_s256_aug1_model')
image_size = 256

def predict_image(image, model=model):
    # Preprocess image
    image = image / 255.
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    # Predict mask
    print(image.shape)
    mask = model.predict(image)[0]
    mask = np.round(mask)
    # Postprocess mask
    mask = np.squeeze(mask, axis=-1)
    return mask

mask = predict_image(image)
```

And this is the adjusted one with the TFSMLayer where predict() doesn't work:

```
model = keras.layers.TFSMLayer('UNetW_bs32_ep25_s256_aug1_model', call_endpoint='serving_default')
image_size = 256

def predict_image(image, model=model):
    # Preprocess image
    image = image / 255.
    image = np.expand_dims(image, axis=0)
    # Predict mask
    print(image.shape)
    mask = model.predict(image)[0]
    mask = np.round(mask)
    # Postprocess mask
    mask = np.squeeze(mask, axis=-1)
    return mask

mask = predict_image(image)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Real error messages would be more helpful instead of "doesn't work". What is the result of the `.predict()` call?

Comment: The error I get is: AttributeError: 'TFSMLayer' object has no attribute 'predict'

Comment: As far as I see it, `TFSM` behaves like a layer (not a model), which has no `.predict()` call. You can try a simple forward call `model(images)` instead.

Comment: Oh nice that fixed it but now I have a different error. I now get an error from the next line so the np.round(mask). I got following error: TypeError: loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type dict which has no callable rint method

Comment: Without knowing the output data, it is really hard to solve this. Try debugging the prediction. It seems that `mask` is a dictionary?